# yadcf plugin and jQuery Datatables filter ordering

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am using `jQuery Datatables` with the `yadcf` plugin to filter on certain columns and wondered what approach I should use to get the column `"Period"` to display the filter in the correct date order.

I can get the Period column to sort OK using a hidden span and a full date i.e. `01/12/2019` but wondered how I might be able to get the filter to sort on load perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sort_as_custom_func`, just set the `sort_as: 'custom'` and provide `sort_as_custom_func` with your own sorting function, in case of issues you can debug the code a bit to see if your sort function is written properly